# Using Java & Magento Rest API. 404 Error

Tags: java, php, .htaccess, magento, rest

I'm trying to use the Java to Magento Rest API using scribe. I have followed the tutorial outlined here. I am new to Magento and REST in general. I am using Java 1.5 on a Tomcat 6.0 server. Magento is 1.8.0.0.

http://gmartinezgil.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/using-the-magento-rest-api-in-java-with-scribe/

So I have currently got oAuth token and Validation working.

```
    final String MAGENTO_API_KEY = "My Key";
    final String MAGENTO_API_SECRET = "My Secret";
    final String MAGENTO_REST_API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/magento/api/rest";
```

I can Authorize the application and get the verifier code fine, but when trying to retrieve the XML(I think?) from the REST URL I get the following.

```
    404 
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC “-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> 
    <html><head> 
    <title>404 Not Found</title> 
    </head><body> 
    <h1>Not Found</h1> 
    <p>The requested URL /magento/api/rest/products was not found on this server.</p> 
    </body></html>
```

I have tried getting data from /magento/index.php/api/rest and the same issue arises.

So this leads me to believe I have left out something for the REST API. Through some research I had seen some changes may have to be made to the htaccess file, but I'm not sure if that is right and what it should be.

These are the entries in the htaccess file  within Magento at the moment.

```
    ############################################
    ## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

    #    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

    ############################################
    ## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

        RewriteRule ^/api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

Any help regarding this would be brilliant. I'm not sure if it is the htaccess file or something else, but I have been trying different things for about a week now to no avail.

Comment: How did you get around this @Murt88?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access any pages other than the homepage in your Magento site at the `/magento/` URL?  Based on the generic (non Magento) 404 page

```
404 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC “-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> 
<html><head> 
<title>404 Not Found</title> 
</head><body> 
<h1>Not Found</h1> 
<p>The requested URL /magento/api/rest/products was not found on this server.</p> 
</body></html>
```

it sounds like your web-server isn't catching the URL rewrite rules that redirect requests to Magento's `index.php` "front-controller/bootstrap" file.

The causes for this are myriad — but I'd check that your `RewriteBase` folder is set correctly.

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /magento/
```

Comment: I tried magento/install.php and it notified Magento was already installed so I assume that the other pages are working. I checked the RewriteBase in the Magento htaccess file and it had been commented out. I'll test it now and see. I may try the sample code in PHP also to see if it a Java issue.

Comment: Okay after uncommenting and restarting and testing I still get the same error. I've tried accessing 127.0.0.1/magento/api/rest/products in the browser as well but I just get the same page. Shouldn't it show some sort of XML accessing it that way? Just somehow to show REST is working?

Comment: Okay so after some more looking around I found this
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/279715/
I had this same issue with my 127.0.0.1/api.php and it resolved this. it still gives a 404 message but that should be as api.php isn't calling anything?

Comment: if I change the String MAGENTO_REST_API_URL in my java program to  "http://127.0.0.1/magento/api.php?type=rest/" it changes the output. It now gives me an error oauth_problem=signature_invalid.

This must show the rewrite isn't working, but why am I getting signature_invalid if I have already authorised oAuth?

Comment: I have the same problem can any of you please help me to solve this.